# Autorefresh function ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, autoload

I have a function in Code behind that returns a Label **lblvisible.text**

```
 protected void AutoloadDen()
 {
    //somecode
    lblvisible.Text = //somecode;
    // i want to autorefresh function AutoloadDen in 5s
    //Such as: Autorefresh(AutoloadDen,5s)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add a timer control on your asp.net markup and add its Tick event in code behind. set interval time of Timer control to 5000 and in code behind call the AutoloadDean() function in tick event of Timer

Comment: Okie. I'm done. But something wrong. Every 5s, it post lblvisible.text. And the, it's continued
My first load is: 001
2nd load: 001001

Comment: Please elaborate a little more. your comment is not clearing your current issue..

Answer (score 0):

Use **[System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)**

```
private Timer timer1; 
public void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 5000; // in miliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoloadDen();
}
```

To call it using `ajax` you need to write a `js` function as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          $.ajax({
              url: "yourpage.aspx/AutoloadDen",
              method: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data){
                    $('#yourtextboxid').val(data);
              },
              error:function(data){
                    //Display error message 
              }
          });
      });
});
```

A little modification in server side method

```
protected void AutoloadDen()
{
    //somecode
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer()
    return serializer.Serialize(YourText);     
}
```

No need of using `timer` on `serverside` in this case